# Underlined TextView Onclick is Not Working ,When Background Service is Running in Android

Tags: android, service, onclicklistener, background-service

I am Using Alarm Manager is sending data to server every 10 minutes.

in same Page i am Using **Forgot Password TextView** With underline.

When **Service is Running in Background**  OnClick event of TextView is Not working.

Onclick of the **TextView** Wants to go next Activity.

But when Service stops Everything Works fine.

Help me to solve this.

```
ForgotPasword = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ForgotPasswordText);


ForgotPasword.setPaintFlags(ForgotPasword.getPaintFlags() | Paint.UNDERLINE_TEXT_FLAG);
ForgotPasword.setText("Forgot Password?");

ForgotPasword.setOnClickListener(this);

@Override
    public void onClick(View v) {


        switch (v.getId()) 
        {

        case R.id.ForgotPasswordText:

            Intent intent1 = new Intent(sign_in.this, Forgotpassword.class);
            startActivity(intent1);
            break;
}
}
```

Log message While clicking Text View

```
07-08 11:59:19.545: I/SurfaceTextureClient(3620): [0x535a3b28] frames:8, duration:3.041000, fps:2.630215
07-08 11:59:21.645: D/IPCThreadState(3620): [DN #5] BR_CLEAR_DEATH_NOTIFICATION_DONE cookie 0x52fc1480
07-08 11:59:41.578: I/SurfaceTextureClient(3620): [0x535a3b28] frames:6, duration:3.007000, fps:1.995112
07-08 11:59:56.482: D/IPCThreadState(3620): [DN #5] BR_CLEAR_DEATH_NOTIFICATION_DONE cookie 0x52f0dcf8
07-08 11:59:56.483: D/IPCThreadState(3620): [DN #5] BR_CLEAR_DEATH_NOTIFICATION_DONE cookie 0x536b80b8
```

Comment: What is the functionality of service?

Comment: Give some logs when you click on the textview while your service is running
Also give details about what is `sign_in`

Comment: every 10 min local database data send to webservice Using Alarm manager

Comment: Accomplish the task using background thread within service.your service will run on main thread.

Comment: @ArunkumarSharma i Added my Log Message, my Sign page having username and Password Edit Text, then One Submit button

Comment: how Can i find my service is Available in main thread or not? @AnoopM

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html

Comment: while Clicking Submit Button I have Added my Service !!

Comment: Agree with Anoop, also I see that you have the onClick method defined at the wrong place. I am assuming that your activity is implementing OnClickListener, which means you should have onCLick method defined inside of you Activity class and not in any method (in this case, the method where you are setting OnclickListener)

Comment: where i have to Add Onclick method in Right Way @ArunkumarSharma

Comment: Just google for adding "android button onClick example"
you should be able to find pretty easily like this one
http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-button-example/

Comment: thank you but, I am Using One button click also can i use same as Example

Comment: so no need to Implement the Onclick listenener ,each onclick Use new OnClickListener() method is Right ? @ArunkumarSharma